# RegEx - How do you isolate a specific sequence of chracters?

Tags: regex

I need to isolate text in between tab ( \t ) and new line ( \n ). Not remove the "\n" and "\t", just grab the text and any other characters like "&" or "()" or "/"

Here is an example of the text:

```
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMilitary & Police Communication Headsets, Hearing Protectors & Accessories\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMilitary Airfield / Shelter / Water Heating Solutions\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPhotonic / Optical Products & Solutions Serving the Defence & Aerospace Markets\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
```

After trying many different combinations, this is the closest I can get:

```
[^\\n][^\\t]
```

I'm hoping I can get some help.

Comment: Try `[^\t\n]+`.

Comment: is that for Python program?

Comment: Yes. It's for a Python application.

Comment: [^\t\n]+  did not work. JSYK, I'm using  http://allregex.com/  to test.

Comment: @user1481614, want to get it work? post your current code snippet

Comment: `[^\t\n]+` works very well in Python. Most probably you pasted the text above into your oh-so-cool Web regex testing site, and wonder why a pattern like `[^\t\n]+` that matches 1+ chars other than tab and newline a string matches a literal string like `\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t`, right? Is that what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/bYg5Ox. If it does not work, show your Python fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Match TAB (`\t`) followed by anything other than newline (`[^\t]*`) followed by newline (`\n`):

```
\t[^\n]*\n
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/yuwQyS)

Comment: Thanks for responding Barmar.   \t[^\t\n]*\n   didn't get anything on my end using http://allregex.com/   Did it work for you?

Comment: Are you sure you put real TAB and newline characters into your test? If you just type `\t` that will be literal characters, not the control character it represents.

Comment: It is literal text.

Comment: But in your Python code they will be escape sequences that get converted to control characters.

Comment: This  [^\\n\\t]   yields the best result for the text I pasted in my original post (above). The only artifact is that [^\\n\\t]  includes (snags) "n" and "t" in the body of the text. I want to negate  "\t" and "\n"  but preserve the "t" and "n" in a word like "tuna".  Re: Python escaping - This is a string comprising the \t and \n combination of characters and not an actual "tab" and "new-line". I need to address them a a sequence of symbols (so-to-speak)

Comment: Don't double the backslashes if you're using a raw string for the regexp.

Comment: [^\n\t]  or  [^\n][^\t]   doesn't do anything... I'm running Ubuntu and I can't find a decent RegEx application to test with on my machine. I have to use things like http://allregex.com/  and I'm not sure if this site is accurately executing the RegEx, mostly because I'm a novice RegEx'er...

Comment: It's difficult to enter control characters in web sites, so testing a regexp that matches them is tricky. You'll have to do it by writing code.